# How to simplify switch case used with preg_match?

Tags: php

I have a string of format:

```
$search_cases = $variable1.'*'.$variable2.'*'.$variable3.'*'.$variable4;
```

where all the variables can be either the string 'no' or a numeric value (integer). I want to cover all possible variations. The only viable way I found to use `switch case` (instead of `if..elseif..`). So my code now looks like this:

```
switch($search_cases) {
    case (preg_match("/no.no.no.no/", $search_cases) ? $search_cases : !$search_cases): echo 'no filter <br />'; break;
    case (preg_match("/(\d+).no.no.no/", $search_cases) ? $search_cases : !$search_cases): echo 'filters used: location<br />'; break;
    case (preg_match("/no.(\d+).no.no/", $search_cases) ? $search_cases : !$search_cases): echo 'filters used: event<br />'; break;
    case (preg_match("/no.no.(\d+).no/", $search_cases) ? $search_cases : !$search_cases): echo 'filters used: artist<br />'; break;
    case (preg_match("/no.no.no.(\d+)/", $search_cases) ? $search_cases : !$search_cases): echo 'filters used: priceinterval<br />'; break;
    case (preg_match("/(\d+).(\d+).no.no/", $search_cases) ? $search_cases : !$search_cases): echo 'filters used: location event<br />'; break;
    case (preg_match("/no.(\d+).(\d+).no/", $search_cases) ? $search_cases : !$search_cases): echo 'filters used: event artist<br />'; break;
    case (preg_match("/no.no.(\d+).(\d+)/", $search_cases) ? $search_cases : !$search_cases): echo 'filters used: artist priceinterval<br />'; break;
    case (preg_match("/(\d+).no.no.(\d+)/", $search_cases) ? $search_cases : !$search_cases): echo 'filters used: location priceinterval<br />'; break;
    case (preg_match("/(\d+).(\d+).(\d+).no/", $search_cases) ? $search_cases : !$search_cases): echo 'filters used: location event artist<br />'; break;
    case (preg_match("/no.(\d+).(\d+).(\d+)/", $search_cases) ? $search_cases : !$search_cases): echo 'filters used: event artist priceinterval<br />'; break;
    case (preg_match("/(\d+).no.(\d+).(\d+)/", $search_cases) ? $search_cases : !$search_cases): echo 'filters used: location artist priceinterval<br />'; break;
    case (preg_match("/(\d+).(\d+).no.(\d+)/", $search_cases) ? $search_cases : !$search_cases): echo 'filters used: location event priceinterval<br />'; break;
    case (preg_match("/(\d+).(\d+).(\d+).(\d+)/", $search_cases) ? $search_cases : !$search_cases): echo 'filters used: location event artist priceinterval<br />'; break;
}
```

Of course, instead of echo-ing the filters I need to do various queries in different tables.

What I basically try to accomplish with this is that I have 4 filters on the page (drop-downs - independent from each other), and I try to get the results based on the selected filters. The information is scattered over a few relational tables.

So my question is this: Is there a simpler way to cover the different situations, or there is some other best practice to accomplish the same result? Thanks.

**Edit:**

There are 3 tables I need to pull the data from:

Table: event

[image: table event]

Table: artist

[image: table artist]

Table: price_interval

[image: table price_interval]

Table: ticket_price

[image: table ticket_price]

There are other tables like the location (to pull the name based on `location_id` from event table, and ticket_type and ticket_price (all related to event table as well), but not relevant for the question I guess.

The filters are: location / event / artist / price interval.

The results I need based on those, so if I select a location (leaving the other filters untouched - variable*no*no*no case), the page returns all the events from that location. If I select for example an artist afterwards (variable*no*variable*no case), then the page show all the events where the location and artist mach. Hope it's more clear now.

**Edit2**

Changed the echo's to reflect the different cases. For every case I need different result.

Comment: Why are you using such a "clever" data packer instead of four separate filter variables? It should be possible to build a separate SQL condition for each filter... but of course it's hard to say for sure without seeing the table structure.

Comment: I need to keep the variables separately, exactly because of table structure. For example, the 3rd and 4th variables are from different table, so I can't build one single SQL query.

Comment: This sounds like a case of an X-Y problem. Show us more details, like the table structures, conditions, and the results you expect.

Comment: Please check the updated information.

Comment: How does a `price_interval` relate to an `event`? Which column(s) does the `event` filter look into? This is certainly solvable without regex if you don't combine the filters into a single blob in the first place, and the data you need can even be fetched with a single query, you just need `JOIN`s.

Comment: Added the `ticket_price` table structure. `price_interval` is not directly related to the `event table`, however I simply check the min and max from the interval in the `ticket_price` table (which is related to `event`). The `JOIN` method could be an interesting solution, surely would simplify it. I am opened to suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is certainly solvable without any regex involvement, and you should just submit the four filters as separate input variables instead of this monstrosity, then build the needed query/condition for each of them.

<sub>I have not actually tested this code against an actual DB.</sub>

```html
<!--
HTML for the form
  if the user hasn't selected any value, just use a blank value 
  instead of a magic string "no"
-->

<form>
    <select name="filters[location]">
        <option value=""> - Select location - </option>
        <option value="1">Location 1</option>
        ....
    </select>
    ..other filters..
</form>
```

---

```php
// PHP code to process search

$query = 'SELECT ev.* FROM event ev';

$joins = array();

$conditions = array();

$params = array();

if(!empty($_POST['filters']['location'])) {
    $location = $_POST['filters']['location'];
    $conditions []= 'ev.location_id = :location_id';
    $params[':location_id'] = $location;
}

if(!empty($_POST['filters']['artist'])) {
    $artist = $_POST['filters']['artist'];
    $joins []= 'INNER JOIN artist a ON a.event_id = ev.id';
    $conditions []= 'a.id = :artist_id';
    $params[':artist_id'] = $artist;
}

// since you haven't explained what the "event" filter does, I'm taking a wild guess - adjust if needed
if(!empty($_POST['filters']['event'])) {
    $event = $_POST['filters']['event'];
    $conditions []= 'ev.category_id = :cat_id OR ev.sub_category_id = :sub_cat_id';
    $params [':cat_id'] = $event;
    $params [':sub_cat_id'] = $event;
}

// it's not entirely clear to me how the tables involved in this filter connect with each other - adjust if needed
if(!empty($_POST['filters']['price'])) {
    $price = $_POST['filters']['price'];

    // load the price interval somehow
    $price_interval = getPriceInterval($price);

    $joins []= 'INNER JOIN ( SELECT DISTINCT event_id FROM ticket_price tp WHERE tp.price BETWEEN :minPrice AND :maxPrice ) p ON p.event_id = ev.id';
    $conditions [':minPrice'] = $price_interval['minval'];
    $conditions [':maxPrice'] = $price_interval['maxval'];
}

if(count($joins)) {
    $query .= ' ' . implode(' ', $joins);
}

if(count($conditions)) {
    foreach($conditions as $ix => $condition) {
        $conditions[$ix] = '(' . $condition . ')';
    }
    $query .= ' WHERE ' . implode(' AND ', $conditions);
}

// you can dump the query here to see the final SQL and parameters
// var_dump($query, $params);

// here I'm assuming you're using PDO for DB access
$finder = $db->prepare($query);
$finder->execute($params);

$events = $finder->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

---

Sidenote: you need to read up on what the `255` in MySQL column declaration `int(255)` actually means.

Comment: Thank you very much for the hints. It pointed me to the right direction. While I had to tailor your example code to fit my needs (for certain reasons still have to stick with the almost deprecated `mysql*` commands)(I know, I know, I hear you..), all the testings I've done so far are showing a right functionality, so I accepted your answer. Thank you again.

Comment: Also, I've read upon `int(255)` as you suggested. Never gave me error, so I thought it will be fine. Anyway, in the future I'll use `int(11)` or if really needed `bigint`. Thank you for pointing that out.